# Convert "Sat 5 Jul" to "05-07-2014"

Tags: php

I would like to convert the string Sat 5 Jul to 05-07-2014 in php. Is there an easy function to do this?  Interestingly the string does not contain the year.

Comment: `date_parse()` + string funcs

Comment: http://codepad.org/GlUwPkx7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need this one:

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime("Sat 5 Jul"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you could convert your string to a timestamp and then give it the format you like.

```
$originalDate = "Sat 5 Jul";
// converting it to timestamp
$timestamp = strtotime($originalDate);
// format it as you prefer (without year)
$newDate = date("d-m", $timestamp);
// print out the result
echo $newDate;
```

the output's going to be this:

> 05-07